# How to define the user and group for directories inside and RPM using FPM?

Tags: rpm, fpm

RPMs have been built using [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). When the `--rpm-user` and `--rpm-group` parameters are used the `%defattr(-,user,group,-)` attribute is part of the `%files`, but not part of the `%directory` section.

How to define the user and group for directories inside and RPM using FPM?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/issues/245

Comment: Does the recently-added `--directory` flag for FPM solve the problem?  See https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/blob/master/CHANGELIST and https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/pull/260

Comment: @LarsRohrbach Please add this comment as an answer. I have confirmed that the mentioned flag solved the issue.

Comment: @Alfred Done, but it's unclear to me whether `--directory` is the correct solution, or `--directories`. Feel free to edit my answer if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

A `--directories` parameter was added to FPM, which may solve this problem.

From https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/pull/260:

> I've added a --directories argument to FPM which causes the values to
>   be added as %dir entries under the file list, so they take the
>   --rpm-user and --rpm-group as owners and get removed when the RPM gets removed. As you can see, it works just like --config-files.

There is also a separate `--directory` flag, which lets you mark a directory as being owned by a package.